# How can I run 2 projects with different ruby/rails versions on the same system with nginx server

Tags: ruby, nginx, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, rvm

I have 
Two Rails projects with a different version of ruby and rails in it, 
I am using Nginx server to run these project in production.
I am using Rvm to maintain different versions of ruby/rails.
My nginx.conf is as:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name ec2-34-222-63-71.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /home/ec2-user/apps/tukatech_garmentstore_live/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    rails_env    production;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8@5.0.2/wrappers/ruby;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

}
```

For 2nd project:

```
server {
    listen 3000;
listen [::]:3000 ipv6only=on;

server_name ec2-34-222-63-71.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

# Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
root /home/ec2-user/apps/tukaweb/public;

# Turn on Passenger
rails_env    production;
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_ruby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/bin/rails;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
```

}

and when I error.log file of Nginx.

```
     - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/passenger-6.0.0 is not secure: it can be modified by user ec2-user
 - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems is not secure: it can be modified by user ec2-user
 - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8 is not secure: it can be modified by user ec2-user
 - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems is not secure: it can be modified by user ec2-user
 - /home/ec2-user/.rvm is not secure: it can be modified by user ec2-user
 - /home/ec2-user is not secure: it can be modified by user ec2-user
```

Please correct the thing which I am doing something incorrect the configuration. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `passenger_ruby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@rails5.1.2/bin/rails;` in the second project!? Isn't that the rails executable? 

I think you ran a `chmod -R 777 .` on your home directory during your debugging because you got an error somewhere? Those errors are permission issues. You need to close them down.

Comment: yes updated it to: passenger_ruby /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby;

Comment: The error is changed to error inside the application  thank you @VaibhavKaushal